# Integrate lottie-player in existing JSF webapp

Tags: jsf, lottie

We need to integrate lottie animations in our existing JEE8 webapp (JSF). But when the following code (lottie-player) was written in the xhtml page, it is not rendered in the client side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
.........
<h1>Header Here</h1>
<lottie-player src="https://assets7.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_umoglgxj.json"  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"  loop="true"  autoplay="true"></lottie-player>
......
</html>
```

Client side output:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
    <head id="j_idt2">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<h1>Header Here</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why it is not rendered? Other tags like DIV, VIDEO, SLOT were rendered without problems.

Using: Payara-Micro, Java17, JEE8, Primefaces and last lottie.

Comment: Hard to tell without a [mcve]

Comment: @Jasper de Vries updated question

Comment: Any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: @Jasper de Vries No errors in browser console or in the server log (TRACE level)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It's simply rendered for me in https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test